# Custom ubuntu file manager shortcuts

Tags: nautilus, filemanager

Is it possible to make the file manager of Ubuntu use the same shortcuts as Chrome?

I mean:

- <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>tab</kbd> open the next tab,
- <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> opens a new tab,
- <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>W</kbd> close the current TAB

Is that possible?

Comment: I'm using 14.04 the captain-nemo owner said :Due to the removal of important features in Nautilus version 3.6 this plugin is no longer supported

Comment: Sorry wrong link I said, I used this link : http://www.techsupportalert.com/content/tips-and-tricks-ubuntu-after-installation-ubuntu-1404.htm

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two of the the shortcuts (in Nautilus) should do what you want already:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> - opens new tab
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> - closes current tab

To select the next tab, you can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Page Down</kbd>. You may be able to edit this by editing the file at `~/.config/nautilus/accels` - though it may not be possible to use the <kbd>Tab</kbd> key in a shortcut - you need to edit this line:

```
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/ShellActions/TabsNext" "<Primary>Page_Down")
```

I think you also need to remove the `;`.

Comment: It is also possible to use `Ctrl`+`1`...`9` to switch tabs in nautilus (I guess that this is also possible in Chrome). This is not as convenient as `Ctrl`+`Tab`, but no additional configuration is needed.

Comment: @Kai - you mean `Alt`+`1`..`9` - `Ctrl`+`1`/`2` changes the view (in Nautilus 3.8 atleast)

Comment: Oops, I'm sorry - As far as I can remember there are some differences between the original nautilus and the nautilus installed in Ubuntu 14.04 (e.g. the nautilus in Ubuntu 14.04 has menus and other shortcuts and the type-ahead feature etc.). I did not think about that.

Comment: @Kai - Nautilus 3.10.1 in Ubuntu 14.04 as well :)